# Python Function to get data from excel which has 1000 Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pyspark, azure-functions

I have a very large excel file and it gets crashed every time whenever I try to find some data so now I'm planning to store the file in Azure Blob Storage/other database and trying to write an Azure function in python so that I can fetch the data from Azure Blob/DB.

I have 1000 Columns and need a dynamic query so that end user can put any column out of 1000 columns to get the data from the excel which is stored in Blob/DB.

Could someone please help me to solution for the same. Which DB would be best and which python library I can use.

I will trigger azure function from Azure API management.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Microsoft example docs for quering Azure Cosmos using the python SDK [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-python?tabs=azure-portal%2Cwindows#query-items).  Once we know how to hardcode an azure cosmos query with python, we only need to make it dynamic.  Meaning we let the
user specify the column name.

One way you could do that is by creating an azure function that performed the database query.  You would allow the user to specify the column name in url query parameters.

As an example, imagine we have an Azure function that is hosted at

```
https://my-function-app.azurewebsites.com/api/httptrigger1
```

We would let the user specify which column they would like data from using the url query parameters. They could add which column at the end of url.  Example ...

```
https://my-function-app.azurewebsites.com/api/httptrigger1?MyColumn=Column1
```

An Azure function can read the url query parameters.  They are part of the incoming request object. So, you could use them to dynamically build your sql statement ...

```
var myColumn = req.Query["MyColumn"];  // Get column name from url query params
QUERY = $"SELECT {myColumn} FROM MyTable";  // build dynamic query
```

This would allow your user to select their own column using the url!

*Note: Be sure to sanitize and parametrize those user inputs to protect against sql injection.*